# How to read files from a UNC-specified directory in R?

Tags: r, unc

Is it possible to read files from a UNC-specified directory in `R`? I'd like to do it without using any packages beyond the base installation.

Comment: sorry if this is an ignorant question, but what is a UNC-specified directory?  Can we have a little more context?  (OK, http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm ). Can you give an example please?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think there is a way to give an MWE. By UNC, I mean the drive names that start with "\\". Those are unique, while the drive letter might change from one computer to another within a network. I'm writing a script which is to be integrated into a software project. The `R` script is called from the command line and gets a path as an argument where further information (data files etc.) are found. However, `R` seems not to recognize the UNC name, while only UNC names are used within the software project.

Comment: Recognizing that this is years old, but a suitable example would just be an example filepath such as `'\\S:\directory\file.txt'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UNC names work fine, you just have to escape them correctly. This works for me:

```
read.csv('\\\\COMPUTER\\Directory\\file.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

adding to nograpes answer ... you can avoid the escaping ugliness by using forward slashes ... this works as well

```
read.csv('//COMPUTER/Directory/file.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

a slightly more cross-platform approach

```
# the two '' are required to represent the two leading slashes of the UNC path
read.csv(file.path('', '', 'COMPUTER', 'Directory' 'file.txt'))
```

Comment: UNC is a Windows thing: does this even work on other platforms?