# Read remote file beginning with "smb://" using R

Tags: r, remote-access, smb

To read a file in `R`, I'd normally do something like the following:

```
read.csv('/Users/myusername/myfilename.csv')
```

But, I'm trying to read a file located on a remote server (Windows SMB/CIFS share) which I access on my Mac via the *Finder* → *Go* → *Connect to Server* menu item.

When I view *that* file's properties, the file path is different than what I'm used to. Instead of beginning with: `/Users/myusername/...`, it is `smb://server.msu.edu/.../myfilename.csv`.

Trying to read the file, I tried the following:

```
read.csv('smb://server.msu.edu/.../myfilename.csv')
```

But, this didn't work.

Instead of the usual *"No such file or directory"* error, this returned:

> smb://server.msu.edu/.../myfilename.csv does not exist in current working directory

I imagine the file path needs a different format, but I can't figure what.

How can you read this type of file in `R`?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88779/how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-from-r-on-ubuntu-to-a-2nd-ubuntu-machine-using) will help.

Comment: Do you see something familiar when you run `ls /Volumes/share` on the command prompt once you've mounted the server volume?

Comment: Sorry, naive question, does which directory I'm in matter when I run `ls /Volumes/share`?

Comment: It should not matter because `/` is the top directory. You can just run `ls /Volumes/` to see if the server's volume has been mounted. Its name is usually `share`.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with R.

Comment: @HongOoi sure it does. That helps determine the path to file that you can give to the read.csv function.

Comment: @Abdou with both `ls /Volumes/share` and `ls ~/Volumes/share` `No such file or directory` is returned

Comment: @RichScriven thanks, my understanding is I have to mount the drive - is that different than the process I followed (`Finder` -> `Go` -> `Connect to Server`)?

Comment: @Abdou it looks like `/Volumes/lastdirectoryinfilepath/filename.csv` worked - the `smb://educ-srvmedia1.campusad.msu.edu/...` part of the path was not needed

Comment: In general I would use @Anony-Mousse 's solution number 1 but on my windows machine I have to explore manually in the path once in file explorer for `source` to work (and probably `read.csv`). Probably for the mapping to be initialized by windows. Alternatively you could also copy the file to a local directory with a shell command called from R with `system`, then use `read.csv` on your new path, and optionally remove the local file.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper On Windows, we can [automate that step](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from our program if desired/appropriate: `system("net use /user:domain\\username \\\\host.example.com\\share")`

Comment: @Cy Rossignol this is great! I'll definitely include this in my Rprofile

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Explanation

`smb://educ-srvmedia1.campusad.msu.edu/...` is actually a URL not a file path.

Let's break this down

`smb://` means use the [server message block protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (file sharing)

`educ-srvmedia1.campusad.msu.edu` is the name of the server

`/.../myfilename.csv` is the file share/path on the remote server

You are able to navigate to this directory using Finder on OSX because it has built in support for the SMB protocol. Finder connects to the remote service using the URL and allows you to browse the files.

However `R` has no understanding of the SMB protocol so can't interpret the file path properly.

The `R` function `read.csv()` uses `file()` internally, see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html

> url and file support URL schemes file://, http://, https:// and ftp://

So R returns "unable to locate the file" message because the file cannot be found because the protocol is unsupported. yes, slightly confusing.

## Fix

You need to mount the file share on your local filesystem.

All this means is that the details of the SMB protocol will be handled behind the scenes by the OS and the fileshare will be presented as a local directory.

This will allow R (and other programs) to treat the remote files for all intents and purposes, like any other local files.
[This discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line) shows some options for doing so.

e.g.

```
# need to create /LocalFolder first
mount -t cifs //username:password@hostname/sharename /LocalFolder
```

then in R:

```
read.csv('/LocalFolder/myfilename.csv')
```

## Extra

Windows users can accomplish this easier with UNC paths
[How to read files from a UNC-specified directory in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570102/how-to-read-files-from-a-unc-specified-directory-in-r)

Comment: @andrew how well do you think this answer the question?

Comment: @stacksonstacks is mounting the disc similar to or different from what I do when via `Finder` -> `Go` -> `Connect to Server`.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg it is similar, effectively is what Finder does behind the scenes

Comment: @Joshua the *mount* command mounts a system-level filesystem, while "Connect to Server" mounts the filesystem through [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) for a specific user.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR**

Here's a portable approach that uses cURL and doesn't require mounting remote filesystems:

```
> install.packages("curl")
> require("curl")
> handle <- new_handle()
> handle_setopt(handle, username = "domain\\username")
> handle_setopt(handle, password = "secret") # If needed
> request <- curl_fetch_memory("smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt", handle = handle)
> contents <- rawToChar(request$content)
```

If we need to read the contents as CSV, like in the question, we can stream the file through another function:

```
> stream <- curl("smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt", handle = handle)
> contents <- read.csv(stream)
```

---

Let's take a look at a more robust way to access remote files through *smb://* URLs besides the approach described in other answers that mounts the remote filesystem. Unfortunately, I'm a bit late to this one, but I hope this helps future readers.

In some cases, we may not have the privileges needed to mount a filesystem (this requires admin or root access on many systems), or we simply may not *want* to mount an entire filesystem just to read a single file. We'll use the [cURL library](https://curl.haxx.se/) to read the file instead. This approach improves the flexibility and portability of our programs because we don't need to depend on the existence of an externally mounted filesystem. We'll examine two different ways: through a `system()` call, and by using a package that provides a cURL API.

Some background: for those not familiar with it, cURL provides tools used to transfer data over various protocols. Since **version 7.40**, cURL supports the SMB/CIFS protocol typically used for Windows file-sharing services. cURL includes [a command-line tool](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) that we can use to fetch the contents of a file:

```
$ curl -u 'domain\username' 'smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt'
```

The command above reads and outputs (to STDOUT) the contents of *file.txt* from the remote server *host.example.com* authenticating as the specified user on the domain. The command will prompt us for a password if needed. We can remove the domain portion from the username if our network doesn't use a domain.

**System Call**

We can achieve the same functionality in R by using the [`system()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/system):

```
system("curl -u 'domain\\username' 'smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt'")
```

Note the double backslash in `domain\\username`. This escapes the backslash character so that R doesn't interpret it as an escape character in the string. We can capture file contents from the command output into a variable by setting the `intern` parameter of the `system()` function to `TRUE`:

```
contents <- system("curl -u 'domain\\username' 'smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt'", intern = TRUE)
```

...or by calling [`system2()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/system2) instead, which quotes the command arguments for safety and better handles process redirection between platforms:

```
contents <- system2('curl', c("-u", "domain\\\\username", "smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt"), stdout = TRUE)
```

The *curl* command will still prompt us for a password if required by the remote server. While we *can* specify a password using `-u 'domain\\username:password'` to avoid the prompt, doing so exposes the plain-text password in the command string. For a more secure approach, read the section below that describes the usage of a package.

We can also add the `-s` or `--silent` flag to the *curl* command to suppress the progress status output. Note that doing so will also hide error messages, so we may also want to add `-S` (`--show-error`) as well. The `contents` variable will contain a vector of the lines of the file—similar to the value returned by `readLines("file.txt")`—that we can squash back together using `paste(contents, collapse = "\n")`.

**cURL API**

While this all works fine, we can improve upon this approach by using a dedicated cURL library. This [curl package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#getting_in_memory) provides R bindings to [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) so that we can use the cURL API in our program directly. First we need to install the package:

```
install.packages("curl")
require("curl")
```

<sup>(Linux users will need to [install libcurl development files](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#installation).)</sup>

Then, we can read the remote file into a variable using the `curl_fetch_memory()` function:

```
handle <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(handle, username = "domain\\username")
handle_setopt(handle, password = "secret") # If needed
request <- curl_fetch_memory("smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt", handle = handle)
content <- rawToChar(request$content)
```

First we create a `handle` to configure the request by setting any authentication options needed. Then, we execute the request and assign the contents of the file to a variable. As shown, set the `password` CURLOPT if needed.

To process a remote file like we would with `read.csv()`, we need to create a streaming connection. The `curl()` function creates a connection object that we can use to stream the file contents through any function that supports an argument returned by the standard `url()` function. For example, here's a way to read the remote file as CSV, like in the question:

```
handle = new_handle()
...
stream <- curl("smb://host.example.com/share/file.txt", handle = handle)
contents <- read.csv(stream)
```

Of course, the concepts described above apply to fetching the contents or response body over *any protocol* supported by cURL, not just SMB/CIFS. If needed, we can also use these tools to download files to the filesystem instead of just reading the contents into memory.

Comment: Nice trick, Cy! Thanks for contributing this, I never new `curl` could support this.

Comment: Nice use of `curl`. It's worth noting that in recent versions of Samba, this won't work with the default server configuration as `curl` only support SMB1 protocol and NTLMv1 auth method and those are disabled by default in Samba (recent versions use SMB2/3 and NTLMv2).  Samba server config must be changed in order to accept the older protocol and authentication method (`server min protocol = NT1` and `ntlm auth = yes`), but this pose a security risk and most sys admins will not allow it.

Answer (score 7):

Below I've shown a way that I've used from time to time to read data from an SMB network drive. In the code below, I've used the R `system` function to do everything from within R, but you can also mount the drive from the OSX command line or from within Finder with Command-K (connect to server):

If you don't already have one, create a directory on your local drive where the share will be located (this isn't necessary, as you can mount the drive in an existing location):

```
system("mkdir /Users/eipi10/temp_share/")
```

or

```
dir.create("/Users/eipi10/temp_share/")
```

Mount the network drive to the folder you just created. In the code below, `//username@domain.address.edu/home/u/eipi10` is your user name and the address of the SMB share.

```
system("mount_smbfs //username@domain.address.edu/home/u/eipi10 /Users/eipi10/temp_share")
```

If there's password authentication, then the password can be included as well:

```
system("mount_smbfs //username:password@domain.address.edu/home/u/eipi10 /Users/eipi10/temp_share")
```

Read the data:

```
dat = read.csv("/Users/eipi10/temp_share/fileToRead.csv")
```

From within R, you can also programmatically select files to read:

```
data.list = lapply(list.files(pattern="csv$", "/Users/eipi10/temp_share/", full.names=TRUE), read.csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

SMB is the Windows network folder protocol.

Similar cases include `sftp://` URLs, for example.

You can either:

1. mount the folder in your operating system, and access it using a regular path,
2. use a virtual file system library, such as GVFS/GIO on Linux. Maybe there exists some R wrapper around this that you can use.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/natritmeyer/6621231 for info about how to use option 1.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is two way to achieve your goal.

- The first one is to use fstab to **add definitely the remote folder** as local disk.
- The second one is to **temporary mount the remote folder** as a folder when it is required

---

Bellow, I will explain how the second method can be implemented

- Create a local directory :

  `mkdir <mountdirectory>`
- Mount your remote directory to the local with this command line :

  `sshfs <remoteserverip>:<remotedirpath> <mountdirectory>` **for SSH**

  **OR** (first install cifs util: `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`)

  `mount -t cifs -o username=<USERNAME>,password=<PASSWD> //<remoteserverip>/<remotedirpath> <mountdirectory>` **for SMB**
- ***Do the job with local file*** !
- At the end, use this command to unmount :

  `fusermount -u <mountdirectory>`